# Android floating Menu Key button for phones without menu key?

Tags: android, menu

I'm trying to get my floating button to work as the menu key for android phones without menu keys also cause one of my apps required a menu key to display the menu list, now my problem is that i don't know how to create the on click function to bring out the menu using the code from the following location.

https://gist.github.com/Jogan/9def6110edf3247825c9

Any help is appreciated.
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was simple lol

```
fabButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) 
        {
            openOptionsMenu();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you asking about floating menu? if yes then here is the solution

```
    Toolbar toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
    toolbar.showOverflowMenu();
```

You can instantiate toolbar object inside onCreate method and then call the showOverFlowMenu method of the toolbar instance.

Comment: I'm using a fixed menu the closer i got it to do is to travel to another class.